# How to get the content of a lit element bounded with Vaadin 23

Tags: vaadin, lit

I followed this [guide](https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/create-ui/templates/components) to Bind an element to my Java class.

```
@Id("editor")
private Div editor;
...
public List<Component> getEditorChilds(){
    List<Component> children = new ArrayList<>();
    editor.getChildren().forEach(children::add);
    return children;
}
```

That works well so far. I can see an instance of the Div element (with the editor id) if I debug the code.
Inside the div there is the content I am interested in.

```
@state() root: Element | null = null;
@state() content: string = "";

render() {
    return html`
        <main>
            <div id="editor-actions">
                <div id="toolbar">
                    ${toolbar(this.shadowRoot!, this.getSelection(), (command, val) => {
                        document.execCommand(command, false, val);
                        console.log("command", command, val);
                    })}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="editor">${this.root}</div>
        </main> `;
}
```

The content within the browser will then look like this:

```
<div id="editor"><body contenteditable="true">
   Lorem <b>ipsum </b>dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy 
   eirmod tempor <br>invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
   At vero eos et accusam<br>...</body>
</div>
```

Unfortunately if I try to get any child within the Vaadin Java class with the getEditorChilds() for example I get an empty list.

How can I get the content of the div or the body (contenteditable) from within the Java class? Or is it even possible to get the content directly from the state property?

Thanks and Best Regards

Answer (score 2):

Except for some special cases, the state that you define in a Lit template will be present only in the browser.

So you need to specifically set the property to be synchronized to the server. We can study [TabSheet](https://github.com/TatuLund/TabSheet) component as an example case of this. I will not copy full code here, but highlight the essential parts. First, you should use `@property` instead of `@state` decorator in your web component.

```
@customElement('tab-sheet')
export class TabSheet extends ThemableMixin(LitElement) {

  @property()
  selected = 0;
...

selectedChanged(e: TabsSelectedChangedEvent) {
  ...
  selectedChanged(e: TabsSelectedChangedEvent) {
  this.selected = page;
  const event = new CustomEvent('tab-changed', {
    detail: details,
    composed: true,
    cancelable: true,
    bubbles: true       
  });
  this.dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

Then you need to fire a custom event upon your property change and observe it in your Java code.

```
@DomEvent("tab-changed")
public static class TabChangedEvent<R extends TabSheet>
        extends ComponentEvent<TabSheet> {
   ...
}
```

And finally mark your getter in Java code using `@Synchronize` annotation.

```
@Synchronize(property = "selected", value = "tab-changed")
public int getSelectedIndex() {
    return this.getElement().getProperty("selected", -1);
}
```

There are more use full hints in [Create a custom component with Lit](https://vaadin.com/blog/creating-a-custom-component-with-lit) tutorial.

Answer (score -1):

I solved this by calling a Javascript function which will return the content of the element:

```
editor.getElement().callJsFunction("getEditorContent")
     .then(String.class, text -> {
         save(text);
     });
```

Comment: This is not the preferred way to do it. See for example this tutorial for more help: https://vaadin.com/blog/creating-a-custom-component-with-lit