# lit templates and java binding does not work

Tags: vaadin

I want to make a lit template for a component and bind to java class.
So that when I instantiate it from java and add to my page/layouts, then it gets formatted like the template is in ts file and can access it value from UI in java backend.

I followed https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/create-ui/templates/components
When I add and instantiate it (MainPage) via new() and add to layout its rendered, listener also works.
But when in callback method of listener, I want to see the content of div

```
    <div id="content">ABC</div>
```

then it is empty. I see id debug the div object is instantiated, but does not have the value of ABC...

So for me looks, like the binding does not work.

Comment: What do you mean by ' in callback method of listener, I want to see the content of div'? Can you please share your code and explain what exactly is not working for you?

Comment: the java and ts is exectly same as in link.
the only change I made is in ts: 
<div id="content">ABC</div> - to get something in div in UI.
And in java:
    public MainPage() {
        helloButton.addClickListener(event -> {
           System.out.println("Clicked!");
           content.getXYZ
        });
    }


Even when I debug, the content object is initialized, but has not value set in ts.

Comment: I find it very unlikely, that Flow would make client side content part of the state on the server, If you want to have controll over ABC, then let the server side steer that.

Comment: I think this has been answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76181151/how-to-get-the-content-of-a-lit-element-bounded-with-vaadin-23